# vertica db: Sum and groupby query while creating a projection

Tags: database, database-design, vertica

Is it possible to create a projection in vertica with the sum and group by sql query.

for eg,

```
CREATE PROJECTION X ...
  AS (SELECT sum(a) FROM Y group by a)...
```

It this is not possible, is there any alternative to achieve this in vertica ?

UPDATE: found out that group by is NOT allowed in projections.

Comment: This is now possible using Live Aggregate Projections.

Comment: Thanks Kermit. This will be a very useful feature. Will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Just an explanation why it isn't allowed. The Select query in the projection is meant to establish the layout of the raw data. Aggregate functions would be better served as part of a view.

Comment: ok. thanks for the explanation. I was basically looking for improved select query performance. So having a view doesn't solve the purpose.

Comment: You can still optimize a projection for your query. The key is to have group by columns in the order by of the projection select statement. If that's not 100% correct, there's something going on like that. You can put your aggregate query into database designer and have it come up with an optimized projection for it.